# automatically transfer any data on excel spreadsheet to master spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I work in a library and I am working on a workbook to track our orders from one company. I have three sheets where each sheet represents a different branch of our library. I am trying to have it set so any time I update information on Sheets 1-3 it automatically appears on sheet 4 as a Master Spreadsheet of orders. I have cells A-H of information (book name, author, order info price etc) that all need to go on both sheets. I am not really great on coding but is such a thing even possible?